# How to differentiate between pinch or zoom in/out using touch pad and mouse wheel event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I had implemented zoom in/out an image using mousewheel event which is successfully working. But the behavior is different when I do that with touchpad(using two fingers to zoom in/out). How to differentiate beetween mousewheel event and touchpad events.

Answer (score 2):

The same wheel event unfortunately fires for both pinch and mouse wheel, so it doesn't seem possible at this time to use a different event.

However, I found that the mouse wheel tends to trigger the `e.deltaY` number in a larger way than pinching.

Thus, I have a listener like so:

```
const handleZoom = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // ignore mouse wheel events that have bigger steps
  if (Math.abs(e.deltaY) > 25) {
    return;
  }

  // do what you want to do with pinching here
}
document.addEventListener("wheel", handleZoom);
```

You can play with the `25` variable to suit your own needs. But for the most part, I noticed that pinch movements are usually much more subtle and have a delta closer to 0, whereas mouse wheel events usually trigger a larger scroll.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to be careful when designing more advanced touch interactions: when the user uses a mouse it will respond via a click event, but when the user touches the screen both touch and click events will occur. For a single click the order of events is:

1) touchstart
2) touchmove
3) touchend
4) mouseover
5) mousemove
6) mousedown
7) mouseup
8) click

This, of course, means that if you are processing touch events like touchstart, you need to make sure that you don’t process the corresponding mousedown and/or click event as well. If you can cancel the touch events (call preventDefault() inside the event handler), then no mouse events will get generated for touch.

Update:
You can identify touch or click like this: 
`

```
$('#element-id').on('click touchend',function(e){
  if(e.type=='click')
      console.log('Mouse Click');
  else
      console.log('Touch');
});
```

`

Comment: I am not using any touch device. I am zooming in/out using two fingers on touchpad/trackpad on my laptop.

Comment: I am using mousewheel event not click event.  Inside mousewheel event we need to differentiate between whether we are doing with touchpad/track pad r using mouse.